# Linux Mint - external screens don't turn on when on docking

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, display, intel

I have Linux Mint 18 running on a Dell. I have it connected to the docking station and 2 external screens attached to it.
After the login screen (which does turn on the external screens on mirror) the external screens go on power saving mode no matter what I do.
This used to work until very recently. I usually update my kernel when the update manager suggests it, could that be it? How do I fix it if it is?

Comment: I'm having this exact problem with my docked Thinkpad 470s. In off chance did you find any solution?

Fwiw, on Gnome desktop this seemed to work and for some time I could get it to work on Cinnamon by deleting `~/.config/monitors.xml` and then redetecting the displays. However, it does not work anymore.